# Исключить все подкаталоги из правил .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache, root

Есть файл `.htaccess` в root директории сайта. Как сделать так, чтобы его правила **НЕ** работали на подкаталоги?

Comment: Какие именно правила? Какого модуля?

Comment: @NoSkill rewriteEngine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно изменить все ваши правила в соответствии с приведенным ниже...

`%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` - это **полный путь** (от корня) в локальной файловой системе к файлу или сценарию (директория тоже считается файлом), которые соответствуют запросу. Тогда можно написать следующие дополнения (в зависимости что вам нужно конкретно):

```
# если REQUEST_FILENAME не является реальной директорией в файловой системе...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# если REQUEST_FILENAME не является реальным файлом в файловой системе...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

# если REQUEST_FILENAME не является реальным линком в файловой системе...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# если ... какое-либо ваше условие ...
RewriteCond ...

# тогда применить ... какое-либо ваше парвило ...
RewriteRule ...
```

Comment: Огромное Спасибо!